# Connect to internet through socks proxy where local DNS does not resolve

Tags: centos, proxy, socks

I have a local machine with CentOS 7. There is a Socks V5 proxy server on the local subnet that provides this machine with access to the internet. I am able to download files with,

```
curl  -x --proxy  socks5://ipaddress:1080 -u username:password www.google.com
```

On my local machine I am currently running Artifactory and Jenkins webapps in Tomcat. The systems do not natively provide socks proxy setup; and require access to the internet.

I tried tsocks, however remote DNS requests are not resolved.

How to I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

So what you provided was the proxy for the curl program to use for that single request.

You may wish to try setting the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables and see if your programs pick them up.

e.g.

```
export http_proxy=username:password@proxy.com:8080
```

These variables would need to be set again on any reboot, so not ideal.

If you are not comfortable with storing these credentials in clear-text in an environment variable you may look to opt for a more robust solution such as cntlm:

- http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Its not an HTTP proxy, but a SOCKS proxy. Exporting http_proxy does not work.

Comment: http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:8080 For example...

Comment: Cntlm if you need something to last longer / not leaving passwords in cleartext etc